# How to turn back into default when i have multisorted the array?

Tags: php, arrays

For example i have array like this.

```
$inventory = 
    Array
    (
        'Team 1'=> Array
        ( 
            'wins' => 100
        ),

    'Team 2' => Array
        (
            'wins' => 400
        ),

    'Team 3' => Array
        (
            'wins' => 4500
        ),

    'Team 4' => Array
        (
            'wins' => 9000
        ),

    'Team 5' => Array
        (
            'wins' => 1
        ),

);
?>
```

I used `multisort` to sorting the array.

```
array_multisort($inventory, SORT_DESC);
```

It's indeed sorting the array. I used `print_r()` and it give me the desired result. After that, i want to call the `$inventory` just like before it was sorted by `multi_sort`. How can i do that ?

I have tried use two vatiable before the array sorted. Like

```
$inventory2 = $inventory;
```

And indeed, It's work. But Is there another way ?

Comment: Why can't you assign this array in two different variables?

Comment: like `$inventory2` = `$inventory` ?

Comment: Yes, You are right. Like this.

Comment: yes, i have tried that. But are there another way to do it

Comment: Have a look at this https://eval.in/873943